# Is there way to further customise notification subscriptions?

Tags: azure-devops

Good morning.

I have a client who has a very specific notification that they want sent out.

There is a custom multi-value control on their Feature WIT that allows the user to select one or more values (that correspond with internal team names). They want a notification to be sent to a custom email address of the team that has been selected. See screenshots below.

[image]

The problem is that when creating the notification subscription, the only filter option available for that field is "changes" and I'm unable to get the value that has been selected.

[image]

Essentially I'd like to be able to do something like: "If 'ContributingTeam' = [ABC] then [send email to custom address]" but I can only do "If 'ContributingTeam' changes then [send email to custom address] but this doesn't help because I need to send the notification to a different email address depending on which team is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side, the drop down seems normal for the field used for Multivalue control:

[image]

Please check whether you choose the correct field, and check what type you used for the field. Also, try to create a new field and try again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  The template has been defined in XML, see below...  `<FIELD name="Contributing Teams" refname="X.ContributingTeams" type="PlainText">`

Comment: Do you mean you are using on-premises TFS (Azure DevOps Server)? Which version of Azure DevOps Server do you use?

Comment: No it's Azure DevOps Services, but they recently migrated from TFS on prem and it required bringing the XML process customisations with.

Comment: Do you have this issue in the original TFS?

Comment: To my knowledge this is a new requirement from the client so I'm not sure if this would have been an issue previously.

Comment: Have you tried other `PlainText` field? How's the result? I don't see there is any option to customize the notification.